How to correctly translate Pari to Cypari 2
to be fair, I have to confess that I have a bit of a mess with the code I tested the other day. I actually had some error where the data type didn't match and it required an int. Meaning I tried to convert the hex values with int(<hex>, 16).
We want to offer a student workshop in which the QR codes of till receipts are analysed and checked. I have already programmed the part with the QR code reading, how to convert some data to hexadecimal. Although not all procedures are covered. We don't want to use software that costs dozens of euros for the workshop, but rather show a few examples of computer science in the workshop, e.g. how to encode, how Base64 is encoded and what else is involved. Just the QR code and other things. So a simple receipt needs a lot of different things from computer science.
That's why I don't want a generally valid method, but show an example that was calculated in Pari more precisely in Pari/GP. The import and other processing has already been completed. I just couldn't get it translated into Python without errors. For our student workshop, it simply means that we give them a few receipts. Using JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook, we want to offer tasks at the end where the intermediate steps can be verified and whether they have already made a mistake (target/actual comparison).
Sorry for the long introduction. I just wanted to say that we are building this step by step to illustrate the computer science and maths behind it, rather than having a code that checks directly at the end whether it is valid or invalid. This means that a lot of converting and understanding the data has already been incorporated. Also various time and date specifications etc. And all the other things you could work out through computer science.
Here's what I do in Pari/GP:
p=0x8cb91e82a3386d280f5d6f7e50e641df152f7109ed5456b412b1da197fb71123acd3a729901d1a7
1874700133107ec53
a=Mod(0x7bc382c63d8c150c3c72080ace05afa0c2bea28e4fb22787139165efba91f90f8aa5814a503a
d4eb04a8c7dd22ce2826,p)
b=Mod(0x4a8c7dd22ce28268b39b55416f0447c2fb77de107dcd2a62e880ea53eeb62d57cb4390295d
bc9943ab78696fa504c11,p)
E=ellinit([a,b])
E[16][1]=0x8cb91e82a3386d280f5d6f7e50e641df152f7109ed5456b31f166e6cac0425a7cf3ab6af6b7f
c3103b883202e9046565*0x1
G=[Mod(0x1d1c64f068cf45ffa2a63a81b7c13f6b8847a3e77ef14fe3db7fcafe0cbd10e8e826e03436d6
46aaef87b2e247d4af1e,p),Mod(0x8abe1d7520f9c2a45cb1eb8e95cfd55262b70b29feec5864e19c054
ff99129280e4646217791811142820341263c5315,p)]
n=0x8cb91e82a3386d280f5d6f7e50e641df152f7109ed5456b31f166e6cac0425a7cf3ab6af6b7fc3103
b883202e9046565

Dx=0x6ED302B701AF28464DB06BA1AC1D31D1AD0DFCC9CD448C7609001CDCE2FF1BE6DB16AF8BD
AFE7E9DD895DDD3B5F6E30D
Dy=0x007D0B82A9474D4F57794D86C2B0CEDF4CCE578B30E71552E89C6B0F9D393780EAAF1D103A
EEC7DFF56FB9F453A31293
D=[Dx,Dy]

ellisoncurve(E,D)

r=0x6ac97526cbdbe99104d0ce4632167b344d68fbaf7194a1a4155774f21fe3d3038b184822980cb30
94cdb5df99a325f70
s=0x060ac3991dff971d42cfe712909453afd0eac8702a33c0f0d21f1dcaa7a4c030cbc62d56f91ea3caed
f66eaa96bec0a7

H=0x
020102060904007F000703070101801146696E6973685472616E73616374696F6E810A594D3458303
534343434822742656C65675E322E32305F302E30305F302E30305F302E30305F302E30305E322E32
303A426172830E4B617373656E62656C65672D5631850253960420001BCB9C53B3B19A658383F6BE
93EBAB7CCFF4D706BB9B60582C775E3C71A4A9300C060A04007F00070101040104020301F6D50204
63185E62

h=0x4abbe1b76cf8b8fc3288795e7e9a733c9a03840d8bbaf683acb3ee63790c749c7052a23a91c285de
daf2ee1ac24880e6

r-lift(ellmul(E,elladd(E,ellmul(E,G,h),ellmul(E,D,r)),lift(Mod(s,n)^-1))[1])

Ultimately, this is the actual test procedure. How do I implement this in Python with Cypari 2? I could also have asked ChatGPT, but I think I used it the other day and then it wanted me to import Mod, for example, which are not available as modules in Cypari 2, etc.
There is a very high probability that this workshop will also be made public and freely accessible on the Internet later on (I work at a university).
Thanks in advance

Can you please clarify why you need Cypari2 here? It's easier to redesign your PARI/GP program to return data you need further in Python. So you would have to run your PARI/GP program and just capture/load its output directly in Python.
